# unable use spring cloud zipkin client

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, zipkin

When I use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The error log is:

```
2017-12-01 18:45:28,185:WARN main (AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperConfigurer' defined in class path resource [springfox/documentation/spring/web/SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAnnotationAutoConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 46
execution (* feign.Client.*(..)) && !within(is(FinalType))
                                              ^

2017-12-01 18:45:28,185:ERROR main (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:581) - Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@61ecbee9: startup date [Fri Dec 01 18:45:24 CST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@703feacd
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at cn.gfresh.OrderApiApplication.main(OrderApiApplication.java:22) [classes/:?]
2017-12-01 18:45:28,190:ERROR main (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:581) - Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@61ecbee9: startup date [Fri Dec 01 18:45:24 CST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@703feacd
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

But when I delete the dependency, it runs normally.

I can't find the reason, I don't know why it's going to be a problem.

this is my fegin interface

I'm using the feign interface  like this

```
@FeignClient(name = "order-service", path = "/order")
public interface OrderService extends BaseLogicService<Order> {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/findById")
    public Order findById(String id);
}
```

this is my parent pom.xml config

```
<spring-cloud-starter-zipkin.version>1.2.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-zipkin.version>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-starter-zipkin.version}
                </version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I tried to modify the POM file, like:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

still error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using a release train BOM or have you provided versions of dependencies manually? Can you show your pom.xml ?

Comment: I use the dependency of the parent pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

It looks a incompatibility between version in my opinion, something is overridden when you inject the spring-cloud-starter-zipkin dependency

What i don't understand from your question is:

**Do you need this dependency "spring-cloud-starter-zipkin", are you using it?**

If no obviously just put it out of the pom, if yes, check which version are you using:

mvn dependency:tree and try to align spring-cloud-starter-zipkin with the Spring version you are using.

Playing a bit with the version of your artifacts you will find the solution.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Yes, I need this dependency on my project to use Zipkin.  

I tried to change the version of spring-cloud-starter-zipkin, but it was still wrong.

Comment: Did you run the dependency tree? which version of Spring are you using and which version of Spring could starter zipkin you need?

Comment: spring-cloud  version is Camden.SR6.
spring-boot   version is 1.5.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Have you already tried to follow the step here ---> http://www.baeldung.com/tracing-services-with-zipkin